# ML.NET Convert type long to DateTime by TypeConvertingTransformer

Tags: c#, ml.net

I have a `IDataView` with `Timestamp` column of type `long`.
I'm trying to convert `long` type to `DateTime` type via **transformer**.
But I'm getting an error.

```
Error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: source column 'Timestamp' with item type 'Int64' is not compatible with destination type 'DateTime' (Parameter 'inputSchema')
```

Is it possible to convert `long` to `DateTime` by `TypeConvertingTransformer`?

```
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;

MLContext context = new(seed: 1);

var rawData = new InputData[] {
    new() { Timestamp = 1590085800 },
    new() { Timestamp = 1590089400 },
    new() { Timestamp = 1590154200 },
    new() { Timestamp = 1590157800 },
    new() { Timestamp = 1590161400 },
    new() { Timestamp = 1674228600 },
    new() { Timestamp = 1674232200 },
    new() { Timestamp = 1674235800 },
    new() { Timestamp = 1674239400 },
    new() { Timestamp = 1674243000 },
};

var data = context.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(rawData);

var pipeline = context.Transforms.Conversion.ConvertType(
    "DateTime", "Timestamp", DataKind.DateTime);

var transformer = pipeline.Fit(data);

class InputData
{
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
}

class TransformedData : InputData
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure what the `Timestamp` long values mean here but basically the [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-7.0) or [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.parse?view=net-7.0) Parse methods don't work with long types which is why I suspect you're seeing this error. You could get this to work using a [CustomMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.custommappingcatalog.custommapping?view=ml-dotnet) transform. Here's a sample of what the code would look like for that:

```cs
// Initialize MLContext
var ctx = new MLContext();

// Create input data
var data = new InputData[]
{
    new () { Timestamp=1590085800L },
    new () { Timestamp=1590089400L },
    new () { Timestamp=1590154200L },
    new () { Timestamp=1590157800L } 
};

// Load data into IDataView
var dv = ctx.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data);

// Define CustomMapping transform
var ConvertToDateTime = (InputData input, IntermediateData output) => 
{
    // Assumes the long represents seconds. Could be used with Milliseconds as well
    output.ConvertedTimeStamp = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(input.Timestamp).DateTime;
    // output.ConvertedTimeStamp = new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddSeconds(input.Timestamp); // Equivalent to code above
};

// Create pipeline
var pipeline = ctx.Transforms.CustomMapping(ConvertToDateTime, null);

// Apply pipeline to data
var outputDv = pipeline.Fit(dv).Transform(dv);

// Get converted column
var convertedColumn = outputDv.GetColumn<DateTime>(nameof(IntermediateData.ConvertedTimeStamp));

// Print out rows
foreach(var c in convertedColumn)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{c.ToString()}");
}

public class InputData
{
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }    
}

public class IntermediateData
{
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    public DateTime ConvertedTimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

When you run this the result should look something like this:

```
5/21/2020 6:30:00 PM
5/21/2020 7:30:00 PM
5/22/2020 1:30:00 PM
5/22/2020 2:30:00 PM
```